# Maple - Solving an ODE with initial values

Tags: math, maple

I'm trying to solve a simple ODE with initial values using Maple (to check my answer). Here's what I'm doing:

[image: ode problem]

However, this is giving me an unexpected result (it's not evaluating the integral, which should be indefinite). What's happening here?

Comment: What version of Maple are you using? There are several things strange happening here. The first is that your **dsolve** command isn't syntactically correct. I'd expect an error message, and I do get an error message in Maple 18. Try using a **restart** command first.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by right clicking the output of `dsolve`, and clicking `Approximate`.

Comment: You should be able to get (and I *do* get, after a few steps) an exact and explicitly solved answer. This is a well-known ODE called the logistic equation. See my comment to your Question above.

Comment: I entered in restart, now what?

Comment: Now enter your ODE, ICs, and **dsolve** command again. That's why I said try using a **restart** command *first*. The *first* means to enter the rest of the commands after.

Comment: When you enter the ODE, put a space immediately after the **k** if you haven't done so already. I can't tell with the small font used here on SE.

Comment: By "worked" do you mean that you got an error message? If not, what did you get?